create two groups with similar values based on multiple variables
i want to create two groups equal size. i want to group my ID base on similar values regarding profit, sales and revenue.
my data looks something like this:
ID    week    profit      sales     revenue 
1       1      50           10         30
1       2      59           15         34
......
2       1      5           1            3
....

if i want to plot my two groups (for example plot revenue) the plot should be as similar as possible, possibly overlap. i have 1200 data points and the data is shown as weeks (1-54).  Notice i dont want only two equal size groups but like i said similar regarding profit, revenue and sales. I use rstudio. Thank you!

Welcome to Cross Validated! Setting two groups to be equal is just a matter of setting group2 <- group1, so I am not sure what you mean. Could you please clarify? Thanks!

Not clear what you are asking but have you investigated propensity score matching?

if i have 1200 observation, i want two groups to be equal size which means group1 = 600 and group2 = 600 (or nearly equal size). But i want to have equal groups with similar values regarding profit, revenue and sales. for example if i plot my profit for each group, the plots would be very similar or almost overlap.

A naive way of doing this would be to randomly partition your data, check if the average profit/revenue/sales values are similar, and if not try another random partition until you find one that works, or use the one with the smallest difference in average values.

Could you please explain why you want two equal-sized groups?  That's tantamount to throwing out a substantial amount of information, suggesting it's an inferior solution to a different but unstated question.

i want an control group and a test group. one group gets a treatment, they other dont. but i want to have groups with similiar characteristics, so i dont test one group with high profit with one group with low profit (not comparable)
